# How do you pass multiple paths to Java -cp command?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

So I am trying to compile a file that imports code from 2+ different .jar files.

The following is the command I am using to compile my file:

```
javac -cp /home/ugrads/majors/quinnliu/workspace/WalnutiQ/build/libs/WalnutiQ.jar:. HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java
```

Now I am getting an error because I am calling code in another .jar file in another folder but I don't know how to add it correctly to my current -cp command above.

Sample of errors I am getting:

```
HowMARK_II_FitsInToBrainAnatomy.java:3: error: package com.google.gson does not exist
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

Comment: Use semicolon `;` as deliminator  (if I remembered correctly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
javac -cp jar1.jar;jar2.jar source1.java source2.java ...
```

On Windows you have to use semicolon to separate the JAR files, but on Unix you can use a colon.